# How to Derive this Matrix Equation - Converting Lagrangian in Proximal Operator Problem Form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, proximal-operators

$$ \left< Z,X-L-S \right> \quad +\quad \frac { r }{ 2 } \left\| X-L-S \right\|_F^2 \quad =\quad \frac { r }{ 2 } { \left\| L-\left( X-S+\frac {Z}{r}  \right)  \right\|  }_F^2 $$

I think $ \left< Z,X-L-S \right>$ should be $\operatorname{Tr}(Z^T(X-L-S))$. This equation is presented in a paper, but the author doesn't show the derivation. See [Robust Principal Component Analysis on Graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06151) at page 11.

Comment: It looks like the trick done for ADMM. Converting the Lagrangian form into Prox Like form. Then pay attention they are equivalent under minimization.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the left side of

$$ \left< Z,X-L-S \right> \quad +\quad \frac { r }{ 2 } \left\| X-L-S \right\|_F^2 \quad =\quad \frac { r }{ 2 } { \left\| L-\left( X-S+\frac {Z}{r}  \right)  \right\|  }_F^2 $$

can be written as

$$
\operatorname{tr}(Z^T(X-L-S)) +  \frac { r }{ 2 } \operatorname{tr}( (X-L-S)^T(X-L-S) ).$$

And this is the same as

$$
\operatorname{tr}(Z^T(X-L-S)) + \operatorname{tr}(\frac { r }{ 2 } (X-L-S)^T(X-L-S) ) = 
\operatorname{tr}\left(Z^T(X-L-S)) + \frac { r }{ 2 } (X-L-S)^T(X-L-S) )\right)
= \operatorname{tr}\left(\left((Z^T) + \frac { r }{ 2 } (X-L-S)^T\right)(X-L-S) )\right)
= \frac { r }{ 2 }\operatorname{tr}\left(\left(\frac{2 Z^T}{r} + (X-L-S)^T\right)(X-L-S) )\right)
= \frac { r }{ 2 }\operatorname{tr}\left(\left(\frac{2 Z}{r} + X-L-S\right)^T(X-L-S) )\right).
$$

The right hand side on the other hand can be written as

$$\frac { r }{ 2 } { \left\| L-\left( X-S+\frac {Z}{r}  \right)  \right\|  }_F^2 = 
\frac { r }{ 2 } \operatorname{tr} \left( \left(L-X+S-\frac {Z}{r}  \right)^T \left(L-X+S-\frac{Z}{r} \right)  \right) 
=
\frac { r }{ 2 } \operatorname{tr} \left( \left(L-X+S-\frac {2Z}{r}+\frac {Z}{r}  \right)^T \left(L-X+S-\frac{2Z}{r} +\frac{Z}{r} \right)  \right) 
=
\frac { r }{ 2 } \operatorname{tr} \left( \left(-L+X-S+\frac {2Z}{r}-\frac {Z}{r}  \right)^T \left(-L+X-S+\frac{2Z}{r} -\frac{Z}{r} \right)  \right)
=
\frac { r }{ 2 } \operatorname{tr} \left( \left((-L+X-S+\frac {2Z}{r})-\frac {Z}{r}  \right)^T \left((-L+X-S)+(\frac{2Z}{r} -\frac{Z}{r}) \right)  \right)
=
\frac { r }{ 2 } \operatorname{tr} \left((-L+X-S+\frac {2Z}{r})^T(-L+X-S)-\frac {Z^T}{r}(-L+X-S)   + (-L+X-S+\frac {2Z}{r})^T\frac{Z}{r}-\frac {Z^T}{r}\frac{Z}{r}  \right) 
=
\frac { r }{ 2 } \operatorname{tr} \left((-L+X-S+\frac {2Z}{r})^T(-L+X-S) + (\frac {2Z}{r})^T\frac{Z}{r}-\frac {Z^T}{r}\frac{Z}{r}  \right) 
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but what I got from the last equation is $\frac { r }{ 2 } \operatorname{tr} \left( \left((-L+X-S+\frac {2Z}{r})-\frac {Z}{r} \right)^T \left((-L+X-S)+(\frac{2Z}{r} -\frac{Z}{r}) \right) \right)$ = $\frac { r }{ 2 } { tr }\left( { \left( \frac { 2Z }{ r } +X-L-S \right)  }^{ T }(X-L-S)+\frac { { Z }^{ T }Z }{ r }  \right) $ I got one more term.

Comment: @Xia you are correct, it looks like I made a mistake somewhere. Will check it again.

Answer (score 1):

The assumed equality isn't true.  The matrices {$L, S, X, Z$} must all be the same dimensions for the math (addition, subtraction, scalar product, etc) to make sense.

Yet, if you generate 4 random $3 \times 5$ matrices, and evaluate the above expression with random values of $r$, you will find that the RHS ***does not*** equal the LHS.

Try it again with random square ($5 \times 5$) matrices, and it fails to hold.

Try it again with square, positive matrices, and it fails.

There might be some unspecified constraint on the matrices that will make this thing  work, but I can't figure it out.

**Update**

Let $Y=(X-L-S)$ then you can rewrite the expression in terms of the Frobenius (:) product as 
$$\eqalign{
 Z:Y + \frac{r}{2}Y:Y &= \frac{r}{2}\Big(Y+\frac{Z}{r}\Big):\Big(Y+\frac{Z}{r}\Big) \cr
 &= \frac{r}{2}\Big(Y:Y + \frac{2}{r}Z:Y + \frac{1}{r^2}Z:Z\Big) \cr
 &= \frac{r}{2}Y:Y + Z:Y + \frac{1}{2r}Z:Z \cr\cr
 0 &= \frac{1}{2r}Z:Z \cr\cr
}$$
This is true when Z is zero, but what's point of it?

Comment: In the paper the $Z$ is refer to the augment Lagrange multiplier, and I don't think it should be zero.